# Simple back propagation example

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, derivation

Sorry if this is too simplistic of a question, but over the last couple of months I have been working through the course mathematical foundations of machine learning at my college. I think I am really starting to understand backpropagation and its innerworkings of how it works, I am just hung up on this extremely little detail.

Assuming the cost function is the standard simple example of: $$J(\theta)=(a^L - y^L)^2$$

I understand that in general we define the "error" in a given layer as $$\delta^L = \frac{\partial C}{\partial z^L} $$
And for a general layer this comes out to:
$$\delta^{L-1} = (\theta^{L-1}\delta^L).*\sigma^{'}(z^L)$$

I am seeing in my professors slides and in Andrew Ng's powerpoint that this derivative for the output layer is just: $$\delta^L=a^L-y^L$$ Why is the error in the output layer not including the derivative of the activation function like we calculate for every other layer? Shouldn't this be: $$\delta^L=a^L-y^L\times \sigma^{'}(z^L)$$

Why do we not have to use the chain rule with the derivative of the activation function for the output layer? This is just driving me crazy, I know there is some simple intuition, I just can't wrap my head around it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123610/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458397/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).